# How is the order of execution of the run method of two threads controlled?

Tags: java, multithreading

Running this code give the following output:

```
 Name of t1:Thread-0
  Name of t2:Thread-1
  id of t1:8
  running...
  After changing name of t1:Sonoo Jaiswal
  running...
```

Should the last "running..." string not be printed just after first "running..." string?
Here is the code--

```
class TestJoinMethod3 extends Thread{
  public void run(){
   System.out.println("running...");
  }
 public static void main(String args[]){
  TestJoinMethod3 t1=new TestJoinMethod3();
  TestJoinMethod3 t2=new TestJoinMethod3();
  System.out.println("Name of t1:"+t1.getName());
  System.out.println("Name of t2:"+t2.getName());
  System.out.println("id of t1:"+t1.getId());

  t1.start();
  t2.start();

  t1.setName("Sonoo Jaiswal");
  System.out.println("After changing name of t1:"+t1.getName());
 }
}
```

Comment: *How is the order of execution of the run method of two threads controlled?* It **isn't**.

Comment: If you go back and look at whatever documentation told you how to create threads, you should see information about how to control their relative execution.

Comment: ...but what that documentation won't tell you is that the more control you exert over the order in which different threads do things, the less benefit there is to using threads in the first place.  Since the whole point of threads is to let you write code that runs concurrently, you get the most benefit if you _let_ it run concurrently.

Comment: @jameslarge ...See also [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).

Comment: You can use t1.join(); t2.join(); right after t1.start(); t2.start(); in case you want your desired output, in that case main thread will wait for the two threads to finish (ie print running...) before executing further.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no** control.

It is that simple. Threads are first of all, independent on each other. Therefore the exact order in which things happen can't be predicted.

If you need to *control* the ways in which your threads progress, you have to look into ways to make that happen (which could be "happens before" relations, or synchronisation points for example).

Answer (score 0):

> Should the last "running..." string not be printed just after first "running..." string? Here is the code--

Not necessarily.  Threads run independently in the background and it is extremely hard to predict when they will run and the timing between them.  If you run your program a number of times you should see different versions of the output.

The whole point of threads is this asynchronous operation.  If a thread is blocking on some IO then other threads can be running in the background processing other information.  That's the power of multithreaded programs.  If you want to control them so that they spit out messages in some order then you might as well just run things in the same thread.